# Height of panel CSS

Tags: html, css

please I have this problem. I have two divs side by side, but the first panel is first and height of container is not good from second panel. I know I badly writing but I dont know better. Thank you for help.

```
#container {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
   margin-top : 50px;

}

#narrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; //may be variable h    
}

#wide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-left: -150px; // half the width
    width: 300px; // must be fixed
}
```

[PHOTO WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzqK.png)

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more. I can't understand it properly. The image is not helpful.

Comment: can you add a HTML snippet of the two divs and the parent? I'm guessing that you want both those divs to be the same exact height?

Comment: To make the question more clear, pls, replace in the question "first" and "second" with appropriate id-s: #narrow and #wide

Comment: Do you want the containers to be the same height?

Answer (score 1):

You have many options but here are 2 of them:
The option **1**

```css
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */      
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</div>
</div>
```

The option **2**

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="column">
        Some content!<br>
        Some content!<br>
        Some content!<br>
        Some content!<br>
        Some content!<br>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        Little content
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice this is what i want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put both boxes inside a parent div with enough space for the 2 children divs, like for example:  550px. Then you add a float left attribute to both children . Please don't use absolute position attribute on the children, otherwise it won't work.

To each child div you can give 240 px of width and to the second one 10 px of margin to the left (to separate them). It is important that they share same attributes.

Same explanation in code:

```
.parentDiv {
width: 550px; 
}

.childRight {
float: left;
width: 240px;    
}

.childLeft {
float: left;
width: 240px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't really understand the question you should not answer. Write a comment on the question instead. This is a pretty poor answer.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent it actually works, it is not a poor answer.

Comment: Your answer is misspelled and has poor grammar. There is no code present and you clearly state yourself in the answer that you don't really know what the OP is asking for. I'd say it is a pretty poor answer.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent I just improved my answer. Thank you for your critique.